# How to show 1 min ago upload image in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, time

I have to display the time difference from the current time in php or codeigniter.

created time 2018-07-19 05:05:22

current time 2018-07-19 05:06:00.

does anyone know how to display 1 min ago in application window.

```
 function time_elapsed_A($secs){
    $bit = array(
        'y' => $secs / 31556926 % 12,
        'w' => $secs / 604800 % 52,
        'd' => $secs / 86400 % 7,
        'h' => $secs / 3600 % 24,
        'm' => $secs / 60 % 60,
        's' => $secs % 60
        );
    foreach($bit as $k => $v)
        return $secs;
        if($v > 0)$ret[] = $v . $k;
    return join(' ', $ret);
    }
function time_elapsed_B($secs){
    $bit = array(
        ' year'        => $secs / 31556926 % 12,
        ' week'        => $secs / 604800 % 52,
        ' day'        => $secs / 86400 % 7,
        ' hour'        => $secs / 3600 % 24,
        ' minute'    => $secs / 60 % 60,
        ' second'    => $secs % 60
        ); 
    foreach($bit as $k => $v){
        if($v > 1)$ret[] = $v . $k . 's';
        if($v == 1)$ret[] = $v . $k;
        }
    array_splice($ret, count($ret)-1, 0, 'and');
    $ret[] = 'ago.';
    return join(' ', $ret);
    }
echo $nowtime = time();
$oldtime = 1335939007;
echo $oldtime = strtotime("2018-07-07 23:29:46");
echo "time_elapsed_A: ".time_elapsed_A($nowtime-$oldtime)."\n";
echo "time_elapsed_B: ".time_elapsed_B($nowtime-$oldtime)."\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you must save the date in `Database` as a timestamp `strtotime(date('Y-m-d'))` then get the time saved in `Database` then use this code.

```
$start_date = 'get the saved date in the database';
$current_date = strtotime(date('Y-m-d'));
$date1 = date_create(strftime('%Y-%m-%d',$start_date));
$date2 = date_create(strftime('%Y-%m-%d',$current_date));
$diff=date_diff($date1,$date2);
if($diff <=  360){
     echo 'show the image';
}
else{
     echo 'not show the image';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/) to do that. For example displaying "1 min ago".

From the momentjs docs you can do this:

```
moment("20111031", "YYYYMMDD").fromNow(); // 7 years ago
moment("20120620", "YYYYMMDD").fromNow(); // 6 years ago
moment().startOf('day').fromNow();        // 6 hours ago
moment().endOf('day').fromNow();          // in 18 hours
moment().startOf('hour').fromNow();       // 35 minutes ago
```